# Create distributable Debug release for IOS react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is it possible to create a distributable "**.ipa**" file for **IOS** as you would with android? Is there a react-native CLI command for this?

I would like to be able to share an application I'm working on with some testers and no idea on how to do this on **IOS**.

Answer (score 1):

We use [hockeyapp](https://www.hockeyapp.net/) for this on both platforms. It has API as well which you can connect to your continuous integration to upload builds and name them automatically. You can upload and edit manually of course. From there the users can download/update the latest builds like on store.

Comment: would this work for applications built with `react-native init`?

Comment: It works on any application setup. All you have to do is to upload `.ipa` or `.apk`.